# How to use SQLAlchemy Max() with joins?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQL statement that I would like to convert into SQLAlchemy (as best as possible).

```sql
 SELECT distinct u.username, u.receipt, u.expires_at, u.account_type, max(r.acctupdatetime) as lastActivity
                FROM user u
                JOIN radcheck c on c.username = u.username
                LEFT JOIN radacct r on u.username = r.username
                WHERE u.account_type != 'life'
                GROUP BY u.username, u.account_type
```

I have achieved most of it by doing this:

```
db.session.query(User, Radcheck, RadAcct)
                .join(Radcheck, User.username == Radcheck.username)
                .outerjoin(RadAcct, User.username == RadAcct.username)
                .group_by(User.username, User.account_type)
                .filter(User.account_type != AccountType.life)
                .all()
```

But I'm stuck on how to do the max on RadAcct.acctupdatetime.

I know the syntax should be like this:

```
session.query(func.max(RadAcct.acctupdatetime))
```

But how can I implement that with the joins here?

Btw the tables have no SQLAlchemy relationship. The username is common across all tables.

Comment: How come `u.receipt` and `u.expires_at` aren't named in the `GROUP BY`? Is `u.username, u.account_type` a key?

Comment: Only `u.username` is a key.  I think the difference between the sqlalchemy syntax above and the SQL statement is that the former joins actual objects, while the SQL Syntax only picks certain fields from them.  I have come across a solution, that I would share tonight.